# How to avoid typing 'python' when running .py scripts?

Tags: python, django

I am experimenting with Django develpment in virtualenv. It is rather anyoing that each time I should type commands like:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I am wondering what should I do to run the same command without 'python', i.e. just:

```
manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the file to be executable with `chmod +x manage.py` and then execute it with `./manage.py runserver`.

Note that if you create your own script files you will have to include the [UNIX shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) in the file.

Comment: I am so lazy so  trying to avoid ./ too. :)

Comment: Isn't there a way to ditch ./ ?

Comment: You're approaching this from the wrong angle. Any decent shell will support autocompletion by hitting the tab key. Telling the shell you want to limit your autocompletion choices to the current directory by using ./ is a *good* thing and makes it much faster to complete the filename you were looking for. In the case of Django's manage.py file I type './m' and hit tab. Boom.

Comment: @wbad check my answer which is for the lazy.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create an alias in your bashrc file like

```
alias python='p'
```

after that execute it using

```
p manage.py runserver
```

**or**

Copy `manage.py` to `/usr/bin/` directory and execute like this

```
manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really must do away with the `./` there is a way.

There are certain paths that python will look to run a file.

Place a file in `usr/local/bin` and make sure it is executable. Then you can run it by just typing the name. That is because `usr/local/bin` is a directory that Python check for executables.

Thats the extent of my knowledge. For more useful info you will want to figure out how to view the PYTHONPATH variable so you know what directories this works for. Also there is a way to add a directory to this variable so you can add a directory with all your py scripts.

I don't know how to do this off the top of my head, and I'm sure you can Google as well as I can.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following django related aliases in order to type less:

```
alias pm='python manage.py'
alias rs='python manage.py runserver'
alias goprojectname ="workon projectname; cdvirtualenv; cd projectfolder; rs"
```

You can put them in your .bashrc or .bash_aliases (preferably). I can just type `rs` to get runserver working or, for instance, `pm syncdb` to sync the database.

[Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/73768/) is how to create permanent aliases.

Answer (score 0):

set `.zshrc` and add this:

```
alias -s py=python
```

when you type `somefile.py`, use `python` open it <=> `python somefile.py`.

Comment: Thanks @David Foerster, this my first answer in askubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

A lazy trick - just add `#/usr/lib/python` on the first line of your Python app, and make it executable using the `chmod` trick above, and double click it and it should work, or in the terminal, 
`./manage.py runserver`
Hope this helps.